# SOLARIS: "du -s" vs "du -sh"

Tags: solaris, du

On all the SOLARIS servers I have access to `du -s` for some reason returns around twice of what it should.

Example:

```
root@someserver:/tmp/testdir# uname -a
SunOS someserver 5.11 11.1 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
root@someserver:/tmp/testdir# which du
/usr/bin/du
root@someserver:/tmp/testdir# ls -la
total 51824
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         183 Nov 14 13:08 .
drwxrwxrwt  20 root     sys         3191 Nov 14 13:05 ..
-rw-r-----   1 root     root     26513019 Nov 14 12:59 test.file
root@someserver:/tmp/testdir# du -s .
51808   .
root@someserver:/tmp/testdir# du -sh .
  25M   .
```

The file is around 25MB, the `du -sh` also correctly reports it as such. But `du -s` reports 50ish MB??

**What is up with that??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally `du` was written to report the number of 512-byte sectors, and that is still the default on many Unix systems.

So your two results are the same.

Comment: Wonderfully intuitive, who the hell thought of that. :P

Comment: It goes back to the days when discs had that sector size. I was around then, which is why I knew the answer!

Comment: Use `du -k` on Solaris to have it report in kilobytes instead of sectors.

Comment: @alanc - I didn't mention that, because the questioner already knew about `du -h`. Also, there are environment variables that can be set to make `-k` the default (I don't know if they are the same on every Unix, but they are mentioned on the manual page `man du`).